# Multiple token injected in to a form

Tags: java, struts, owasp

On my Java Strut application I use OWASP library version 3.1 to protect from CSRF.
Because of complex structure it heppens that I have multiple script tag. It is added on multiple pages and sometimes one page include another.

```
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/JavaScriptServlet"></script>
```

I have problem on Internet Explorer when on same page exsist this multiple tag. If it exsists then it add multiple token to form. I see it when inspect page on Internet Explorer

```
<FORM method=post name=myForm action=/myAction.do?OWASP_CSRFTOKEN=54AE-VJT1-2OZM-4CZV-LMQI-CUEV-BGL1-EQRI&amp;OWASP_CSRFTOKEN=54AE-VJT1-2OZM-4CZV-LMQI-CUEV-BGL1-EQRI&amp;OWASP_CSRFTOKEN=54AE-VJT1-2OZM-4CZV-LMQI-CUEV-BGL1-EQRI&amp;>
```

Also it add multiple input with token

```
<INPUT type=hidden value=54AE-VJT1-2OZM-4CZV-LMQI-CUEV-BGL1-EQRI>
<INPUT type=hidden value=54AE-VJT1-2OZM-4CZV-LMQI-CUEV-BGL1-EQRI>
<INPUT type=hidden value=54AE-VJT1-2OZM-4CZV-LMQI-CUEV-BGL1-EQRI>
```

Has somebady had similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since all the tokens are the same, there should not be any concern with how these pages function.  You should be fine.

The only way to consolidate is to give the script an ID and check if it is present before declaring it again.

Alternatively you could refactor all your JSPs so that in every case a "base" jsp of some kind ensures it is inserted only once.

If you are not seeing token clashes (rejected logs from CSRFGuard) then you have nothing to worry about.